# How to split String array and store the string in another array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array which contains `"-"` . So I have to split these strings to store them.

For example.

`String s[]={"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};`

to

`String k[]={"abc","gt","q","asd","aby"}`

The code I have tried is

```
 public static void main(String...a)
{


String s[]={"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};

int sop=0;

                 String[] sdf=new String[100];

 for(int kk=0;kk<s.length;kk++)
             {

              if(s[sop].equals("-"))
              {

              }
              else
              {
              sdf[sop]=s[sop];

               sop++;
              }

             }
}
```

But It gives first three string. `abc`. What I have to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that :

```
    String s[]={"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};

    String split = "-";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++){
        if(s[i].equals(split)){
            list.add(temp);
            temp = new String();
        }else{
            temp += s[i];
        }
    }

    String array[] =  list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    for(String str : array){
        System.out.println(str); // output : abc;gt;q;asd;
    }
```

Comment: Its simple answer without String builder

Comment: Is a better solution use StringBuilder. Also u are adding empty strings in case there are in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> k = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : s) {
        if (str.equals("-")) {
            k.add(builder.toString());
            builder.setLength(0);
        } else builder.append(str);
    }
    k.add(builder.toString());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k.toArray(new String[k.size()])));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[abc, gt, q, asd, aby]
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add this is array?

Comment: I didn't see this solution. Looks like we thought the same solution ;)
Which is positive :)

Answer (score 1):

you are not incrementing the sop if `s[sop].equals("-")`. you have to increment it everytime. and also it can be reduced to.

```
          if(!s[sop].equals("-"))
          {
              sdf[sop]=s[sop];
          }
          sop++;
```

also instead of sop you can use the loop counter kk;

another alternative way can be,

1. iterate through the first array and contact all element to a String.
2. get the final array using String.split method

   StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
    for(String temp : s)
       sB.append(temp);
    String[] output = sB.toString().split("-");

Comment: Smarter to use the string builder, but using the sop iterator to pull from the s[], is the problem with the code provided.

Comment: I dont know why I can't make the later part as a code .. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here:

- you stop incrementing `sop` when you reach a "-". I think instead of `s[sop]` you might want to use `s[kk]`.
- each time you get new characters, you don't append them to an existing string, but you add them in new array cells

Also, for your second array, consider using an `ArrayList`, as you don't initially know its size.

Here is a corrected version:

```
for (int kk = 0; kk < s.length; kk++) {

    if (!s[kk].equals("-")) {
        if (sdf[sop] != null) {
            sdf[sop] += s[kk];
        } else {
            sdf[sop] = s[kk];
        } 
    } else {
        sop++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic error: You were using the same iterator in both arrays, while retrieving the value from s[], you should be using the for loop iterator, kk.

```
public static void main(String...a)
     {
     String s[]={"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};

     String[] sdf=new String[100];
     int sop = 0;
      for(int kk=0;kk<s.length;kk++)
      {
          if(!s[kk].equals("-"))
          {
              sdf[sop]=s[kk];
              sop++;
          }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to start off with a string array?

You might want to use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to parse your string with '-'.

```
String s[] = { "a", "b", "c", "-", "g", "t", "-", "q", "-", "a", "s",
                "d", "-", "a", "b", "y" };

// Join the letters to make a full string
String s_full = "";
for (String letter : s) {
    s_full += letter;
}

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s_full, "-");  //Tokenize
String[] words = new String[st.countTokens()];
int i = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    words[i++] = st.nextToken();    //Add to result array
}

// Print result
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: Well I guess if you have a full string you can as well use `s_full.split("-")`

Comment: @Joffrey Oh yes.. That would be simpler I guess. :)

Comment: Indeed, it would take one line ^^

Answer (score 0):

Staying in your context:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {


    String s[]={"a","b","c","-","g","t","-","q","-","a","s","d","-","a","b","y"};

    int sop=0;

    String[] sdf=new String[100];
    String temp = "";

    for(int kk=0;kk<s.length;kk++){
        if(s[kk].equals("-")){
            sdf[sop] = temp;
            temp = "";
            sop++;
        } else {
            temp += s[kk];
        }
    }
}
```

Better use a StringBuilder, this is just for understanding the logic...

Answer (score 0):

I'd something like that:

```
String s[] = { "a", "b", "c", "-", "g", "t", "-", "q", "-", "a", "s", "d", "-", "a", "b", "y" };
String delimiter = "-";

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();  
StringBuilder group = new StringBuilder();
for (String character : s) {
    if (delimiter.equals(character) && !"".equals(group)) {
        result.add(group.toString());
        group.setLength(0);
    } else {
        group.append(character);
    }
}

if (!"".equals(group)) {
    result.add(group.toString());
}
```

You could use List or an array string converting using:

```
result.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: I didn't see the solution from Harmlezz. Looks like we thought the same solution ;)